# How do I setup Route 53 to point to Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-api-gateway

I'm writing a Cloudformation config file to create a website all in one go. This includes, creating lambda functions, creating the API Gateway, Setting up a S3 Bucket, Creating the Route 53 zone and records.

So far:

- Creating Lambda functions and it's role (works)
- Creating API Gateway it's deployment and it's role (works)
- Creating a S3 bucket and it's policy (works)
- Creating a Route 53 zone and DNS records for the site (works)
- Create a domain for API Gateway (no idea what I'm doing)

So `domain.com` serves up the files in the S3 bucket without a problem. Using the AWS URI for API Gateway works `https://trydsoonjc.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app/path/here` without a problem.

What I want to setup is a `api.domain.com` to point to the API Gateway to access the server's API.

How do I connect Route 53 to API Gateway?

My Cloudformation as it stand now is this:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description" : "Website",

  "Parameters": {
    "DomainName": {
      "Type" : "String",
      "Description" : "The DNS name of an Amazon Route 53 hosted zone e.g. server.com",
      "AllowedPattern" : "(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{1,63}(?<!-)",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid DNS zone name."
    }
  },

  "Mappings" : {
    "RegionMap" : {
      "us-east-1" : { "S3HostedZoneId" : "Z3AQBSTGFYJSTF", "S3WebsiteEndpoint" : "s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" },
      "us-west-1" : { "S3HostedZoneId" : "Z2F56UZL2M1ACD", "S3WebsiteEndpoint" : "s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com" },
      "us-west-2" : { "S3HostedZoneId" : "Z3BJ6K6RIION7M", "S3WebsiteEndpoint" : "s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com" },
      "eu-west-1" : { "S3HostedZoneId" : "Z1BKCTXD74EZPE", "S3WebsiteEndpoint" : "s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" },
      "ap-southeast-1" : { "S3HostedZoneId" : "Z3O0J2DXBE1FTB", "S3WebsiteEndpoint" : "s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com" },
      "ap-southeast-2" : { "S3HostedZoneId" : "Z1WCIGYICN2BYD", "S3WebsiteEndpoint" : "s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com" },
      "ap-northeast-1" : { "S3HostedZoneId" : "Z2M4EHUR26P7ZW", "S3WebsiteEndpoint" : "s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com" },
      "sa-east-1" : { "S3HostedZoneId" : "Z31GFT0UA1I2HV", "S3WebsiteEndpoint" : "s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com" }
    }
  },

  "Resources": {
    "LambdaExecutionRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
          }]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [{
          "PolicyName": "execution",
          "PolicyDocument": {
            "Statement": [{
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }, {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }]
          }
        }]
      }
    },

    "APIGatewayExecutionRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
          }]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [{
          "PolicyName": "execution",
          "PolicyDocument": {
            "Statement": [{
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }, {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }]
          }
        }]
      }
    },

    "LambdaFunctionUpdate": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {
          "ZipFile": "exports.handler = function (event, context) { context.succeed(\"Hello, World!\"); };"
        },
        "Description": "Update handler.",
        "Handler": "index.handler",
        "MemorySize": 128,
        "Role": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaExecutionRole", "Arn" ] },
        "Runtime": "nodejs4.3",
        "Timeout": 30
      }
    },

    "APIGateway": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
      "Properties": {
        "Body": @@swagger,
        "FailOnWarnings": true,
        "Name": "smallPictures",
        "Description": "Structured wiki"
      }
    },

    "APITDeploymentTest": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
      "Properties": {
        "RestApiId": { "Ref": "APIGateway" },
        "Description": "Deploy for testing",
        "StageName": "smallPicturesTesting"
      }
    },

    "WebsiteBucket" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties" : {
        "BucketName": {"Ref":"DomainName"},
        "AccessControl" : "PublicRead",
        "WebsiteConfiguration" : {
          "IndexDocument" : "index.html",
          "ErrorDocument" : "404.html"
        }
      },
      "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain"
    },

    "WebsiteBucketPolicy" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
      "Properties" : {
        "Bucket" : {"Ref" : "WebsiteBucket"},
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [{
              "Action": [ "s3:GetObject" ],
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", { "Ref" : "WebsiteBucket" } , "/*" ]]},
              "Principal": "*"
          }]
        }
      }
    },

    "DNS": {
      "Type": "AWS::Route53::HostedZone",
      "Properties": {
        "HostedZoneConfig": {
          "Comment": { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["Hosted zone for ", { "Ref" : "DomainName" } ]]}
        },
        "Name": { "Ref" : "DomainName" },
        "HostedZoneTags" : [{
          "Key": "Application",
          "Value": "Blog"
        }]
      }
    },

    "DNSRecord": {
      "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "HostedZoneName": {
            "Fn::Join": [ "", [ { "Ref": "DomainName" }, "." ]]
        },
        "Comment": "Zone records.",
        "RecordSets": [
          {
            "Name": { "Ref": "DomainName" },
            "Type": "A",
            "AliasTarget": {
              "HostedZoneId": { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "S3HostedZoneId" ]},
              "DNSName": { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "S3WebsiteEndpoint" ]}
            }
          }, {
            "Name": { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["www.", { "Ref" : "DomainName" }]]},
            "Type": "CNAME",
            "TTL" : "900",
            "ResourceRecords" : [
              {"Fn::GetAtt":["WebsiteBucket", "DomainName"]}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },

  "Outputs": {
    "WebsiteURL": {
      "Value": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["WebsiteBucket", "WebsiteURL" ] },
      "Description": "URL for website hosted on S3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A custom domain name (hostname) is not pointed at the API Gateway endpoint directly.  It's pointed at the underlying CloudFront distribution, created/owned/controlled by API Gateway *after* API Gateway is configured to expect/support the custom domain name.  This is more complex than simply creating a record in Route 53. You will need to review [Use Custom Domain Name as API Gateway API Host Name](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) unless you are already familiar with this process.

Comment: You'll also need to provide an SSL certificate for your custom hostname, or obtain one from Amazon Certificate Manager, as part of the configuration, since API Gateway requires that HTTPS be enabled.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a SSL certificate using the Certificate Manager. For an edge endpoint, create it in eu-east-1, for regional and private endpoints, create it in the region you are deploying the API gateway in (or the lambda). Read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html). I will refer to the ARN as `CertificateArn`

You have to configure a `AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName`:

```
"MyDomainName": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName",
  "Properties": {
    "DomainName": {"Ref: "DomainName"},
    "CertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:111122223333:certificate/fb1b9770-a305-495d-aefb-27e5e101ff3"
  }
}
```

This enables the Domain for the API Gateway. Next, you need to expose the API (i.e. your RestAPI), in a specific deployment *stage*. In your template, your have no deployment stages. Take a look a [`AWS::ApiGateway::Stage`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-stage.html). A minimal example would look like this:

```
"Prod": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
            "Properties": {
                "StageName": "Prod",
                "Description": "Prod Stage",
                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "APIGateway"
                },
                "DeploymentId": {
                    "Ref": "APITDeploymentTest"
                },
}
```

However, you most likely want some additional configuration in that. I suggest you take a look at the `MethodSettings` property.

At last, deploy a basepath mapping resource: [`AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping`](http://AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping). I suggest you map the basepath to the stage you created like this:

```
"ProdDomainBasePath": {
  "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping",
  "Properties" : {
    "DomainName" : {"Ref: "DomainName"},
    "RestApiId" : {"Ref": "APIGateway"},
    "Stage" : "Prod"
  }
}
```

If you change an `AWS::ApiGateway::Stage` resource, you have to force an update on the corresponding `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` resource - this usually means renaming the `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` resource, to keep that in mind. Otherwise, it wont be deployed.

That should do it.